# How do I zip files individually older than x days using bash? (with user input)

Tags: linux, bash, zip

hey I hope someone can help me with my problem (I'm new)

I want to zip multiple files older than x days. **I already implemented** read the anmount of days and with the find operator I put them into $Files.

But I want to ask the user of the bash script whether he wants to add the file to the archive (or not) and delete the original file then.

The only problem is this yes/no part because I don't know *how I can add (or not add) every file individually.*

**It should look like**: Zip <xyz.pdf> to <zip.zip> and delete the original then? (y/n) (for every single file)

thanks for everyone helping me :D

my code:

```
echo "How old should the file(s) be?"
read anmount_days

Files=$(find -mtime +$anmount_days)

#echo -e "\nZip <xyz> to <zip.zip> and delete the original then? (y/n)"
#read input

#if [ "$input" == "" ]; then
#
#   echo -e "\nNothing was entered by the User\n"
#
#if [["$input" == y]]; then
#
#   zip files
#
#else
#
#   skip
#

# zip -r zip.zip $Files -rm

echo -e "\nxy file(s) older than $anmount_days day(s) from current ${PWD} archieved in xyz"e
```

Comment: Show us your bash script that loops through all of the values in $Files, prompts the user, and appends the affirmative files to $YesFiles.

Comment: here you go, i added the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 1:
Code asks for "y/n" per file before zipping them in zip.zip

EDIT 2:
Show number of zipped files and the files that were zipped.

```
echo "How old should the file(s) be?"
read anmount_days

Files=$(find -mtime +$anmount_days)

# Create blank array
list=$@
newlist=()

for file in $Files
do
    echo -e "\nZip $file to <zip.zip> and delete the original then? (y/n)"
    read input
    if [[ $input = "y" ]]
    then
            echo "Zipping $file to zip.zip"
            #Append $file in array
            newlist+=($file)
            zip zip.zip $file
            #rm $file
    fi
done

echo "Files that were zipped: ${newlist[*]}"
echo "Total number of files zipped: ${#newlist[@]}"
```

When input is **3, and all "y"**:
[image]

Zip file when all "y":
[image]

When input is **3, and 2 "y"** and the **rest is "n"**:
[image]

Zip file when 2 "y" rest is "n":
[image]

Show number of files and filenames:
[image]

Comment: hey, thanks for your hard word :D the problem i want to solve is that I need the user input whether the file should be added or not. So i want to archive all files in one .zip file, but the user still can decide with y or no if he want to skip for example convert_date.sh. So there must be multiple y/n questions for each file.

Comment: Sorry about that. I missed that part. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Is it possible to do an echo at the end about how many files were zipped? when I try to implement that, it becomes part of the loop :/ But thank you so much for solving my problem :D

Comment: @holyshoti I edited my answer and included that.

Comment: hello :D is it possible to provide the data for anmount_days by opening the bash? so instead of the question How old should the files be? just typing ./zip 200 and then having the 200 as anmount_days with checking whether the user entered a number or an invalid letter?

Comment: @holyshoti It is much better to open another question since it not so related to the original post. Just so the community can also contribute.